# Change Dll Folder In Visual Studio 2008 C#

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, dll, directory

I have 2 projects in my solution. The first one is a console application, and the second is a dll, used (referenced) by the console. When I build my solution (release) I get one EXE file and one DLL file, because `copy local` is `true` (if I set it to `false`, it doesn't run).

How can I store that DLL file in a subdirectory? If my output folder is `C:\123\`, and there's the EXE file, I want all my DLLs to be in `C:\123\Dll\`.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159192/howto-load-assemby-at-runtime-before-assemblyresolve-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [probing element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) to specify which paths your application should use when attempting to resolve dll dependencies.

Example:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="123;123\dill"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Also you can use the [Post-build event command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(VS.80).aspx) to copy your dll's to a particular directory.