# C#: cannot find assembly file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005

I am getting an error back from a DLL saying it cannot create an instance of one of classes in my solution because it cannot find the assembly file.

If I am debugging a solution, do I need to put a copy of certain assembly files in other locations?

EDIT:

In my compiled solution all the DLLs (including the proprietary ones) all go in the app directory and it works fine.  But I am trying to work out where the files should do in order to debug the solution.

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace for this exception ?
If you want to debug compiled dll files, you need to provide pdb files also.

Comment: Might also be a bug in the dll.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in the dll.  The dll is looking for my assemblies because it was passed the names of them in some data that was sent to it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the assembly in question in 1) the same directory, or 2) in the GAC, or 3) use AssemblyBinding to define the specific path that the .NET framework.

[MSDN link: using AssemblyBinding to define the referenced assembly path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb(v=VS.71).aspx)

Comment: When you say "the same directory", what do you mean?

Comment: @Craig, I meant the referenced assembly should be in the same directory as the calling assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to add reference of the assembly to the project.

Add the reference, and try again.

Read more here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Surely then it wouldn't compile?

Comment: It does compile. I think the proprietary DLL needs the DLLs of my solution to be in a certain location but I don't what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If they are in your references list, try right-clicking the problem reference in the solution explorer and selecting "properties".  There is one property called copy local.  Make sure that is true. Then when you build, a copy of that dll will be in your bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler to [AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) to find out which library it tries to load. Some sample code and ideas can be get from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159192/howto-load-assemby-at-runtime-before-assemblyresolve-event).

**Update**
To find out, what is the best place for your project you should take a look into [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx) guide. Also to get a *live view* about where the framework searches for your needed dll you can use [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see where it tries to catch it.

Comment: I know which assembly it is trying to load because the Exception is telling me which one.  I just don't know where to put the assembly.  Should it go in the directory of the calling DLL?

Comment: @Craig: Yes, it should go in the same directory as the calling DLL, or the GAC. Otherwise it won't find it.  See code4life's answer