# c# how to load all necessary assemblies into memory on Application startup

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a Winform application in c# that uses tons of assemblies which is very slow upon first time the user open the forms that use these assemblies, is there a way to load all of these assemblies into memory when the application is starting up so the users don't have wait for several seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preload all assemblies (JIT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175743/preload-all-assemblies-jit)

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(path)
```

This is sample from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39(v=vs.110).aspx). In my project I use XML file as a list of assemblies to load and than I search specific folders for dll files and try to load them (they can be native dll's so I can't load it).