# how does linking actually happen internally?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, glibc

There are these questions which I am not able to get answers for. Any help is very useful.

1. How does linking actually happen in the C compilation model?
2. If I am using Linux and GCC, how does `glibc` link to the main program. Is it static or dynamic linking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For your first question a simple one para answer is not sufficient. Read the following resources

   1. [Article on linking at cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html)
   2. [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29)
   3. [man page of `ld`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux)
   4. [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951498/what-is-the-difference-between-linking-and-loading-in-c-language)
2. `glibc` is linked **dynamically** unless you specify [`-static`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) option to the linker. Under *normal* circumstances, linking a huge lib like `glibc` statically doesn't help.