# difference between static and dynamic library in unix

Tags: unix

what is the difference between static and dynamic library in unix?
how can i use libraries in unix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do 'statically linked' and 'dynamically linked' mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311882/what-do-statically-linked-and-dynamically-linked-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static libraries are linked into your executable at link time so are fixed at that point.

For dynamic linking, only a reference to the library is linked in at link time. The dynamic library (the actual code) is linked to your executable at *load* time, when you run your program.

That means you can change the dynamic library at any time and you'll use the new one the next time you load the program.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311882/what-do-statically-linked-and-dynamically-linked-mean/311889#311889) for more detail.