# Does .obj file contains machine code in binary language?

Tags: c

I am confused about .obj files created using C language. Does they contain machine code and is the machine code in binary language, as it is known that the machine can understand only binary language. Moreover, my thinking of machine code is that it is a set of machine instructions in binary language (I may be wrong). Please explain.

Comment: Define `.obj` file please.

Comment: what does this have to do with C or C++, exactly?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I think he is referring to the .obj files created by the Borland Turbo C++ compiler

Comment: .obj file is a file that is being created in C when I compile my program with turbo c compiler. So I think this is very much related with C/C++. Why you guys are bent upon downgrading me. Is it wrong to ask questions here? I know you are highly rated people but does that means that beginners can't be part of this community. Rather than motivating you are discouraging man!!

Comment: @Navdeep you should specify the compiler i.e., **Borland Turbo C/C++** that produces these **.obj** files in your question. **C language** does not produce **.obj** files!

Comment: @Navdeep your question is missing *lots* of details and is answerable by doing a few google searches. It's not personal, it just isn't a good question.

Comment: @CrakC I am using Borland Turbo C++ 3.1.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode actually by doing a lot of google searches I got myself confused, that's why I asked question here. If it's possible for you please explain it here or send me some link that contains some clear explanation about it. The links I found contains lots and lots of information which actually didn't serve any purpose...Thanks

Comment: @Navdeep Pls go through the link that I have posted in my answer

Comment: It is certainly easiest to assume it does.  Not terribly relevant anymore these days, they often contain the intermediate language used between the front-end and the code generator.  To support profile-guided or whole-program optimization, the linker generates the code.  YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

An object file is a file containing object code, meaning relocatable format machine code that is usually not directly executable. **.obj** is the compiled object file that is used by the **linker** (along with the necessary library (**.h**) files) to create an executable. The executable is then loaded into the memory for execution using a **loader**.

Please read the following for more information-
[What is compiler, linker, loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996651/what-is-compiler-linker-loader)

[image]