# Unresolved external symbols when calling a method of an object

Tags: c++

I have class, and in one of its methods I get an object of another class from a vector of objects, and then call a method of that object. The problem is that when I call that method, i get an unresolved external symbols problem, like this:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall GameChar::draw(void)" (?draw@GameChar@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Application::gameLoop(void)" (?gameLoop@Application@@QAEXXZ)
```

The method where I call the other object's method is gameLoop() and I call the draw() method of the other object. I've checked that all methods of the other class are defined, because I read that not defining a method is often the problem.

Comment: How are you compiling it? The only two problems this could be is that something is declared but not defined, or you are not compiling the .cpp file in with the project (which is the same thing as it being not defined in the first place)

Comment: possible duplicate of [LNK2019 error c++ unresolved external symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730135/lnk2019-error-c-unresolved-external-symbol)

Comment: You need to show the code that defines the method and the code that calls it.  Also, what compiler is this?

Comment: Yes, one reason could be that the `draw` function doesn't exist. Another reason could be that it does exist, but in a file that isn't linked to the executable (because it perhaps wasn't added to the project).

Comment: @SethCarnegie Well, I have the class definition and the method definitions on the same .h file (because if i include .cpp files it gives me errors) , I'm a beginner on c++ and I don't know if I can do that, maybe that is the problem. I'll try putting the method definitions in a cpp file

Comment: Is the definition `void draw() { // the code }` or `void GameChar::draw() { // the code } ` ?

Comment: If you have this all in a project, just include the .h file from the main file and the implementation file. If you're using CodeBlocks and not using a project, you'll need to put in a header guard (something that you should be doing anyways) and include the .h in both main and the implementation, as well as including the implementation in main.

Comment: the draw method is defined as void GameChar::draw(){}, and I have it all in a proyect. Tomorrow I'll split the code into header and implementation files and I'll tell

Comment: We might be able to find something if you post your code as well.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is that I some files imported from other project, but also copyed to my project directory, and they had different codes. I deleted all the files from my project and then I readded them. Now it doesn't give me that error anymore. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just had the same issue with Visual Studio 2012. Everything was set up correctly, but only re-adding helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the function has been declared but not implemented. Whether it's in the same file, a .cpp file, or library, the body of the function needs to be there before you can use it.

As hmjd pointed out, this can commonly happen when you put

```
void draw()
{
    ...
}
```

instead of

```
void GameChar::draw()
{
    ...
}
```

The former declares a global function, whereas the the latter scopes it to the class `GameChar`.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to watch out for; make sure your .cpp files are actually showing up in your project files; I could not figure out a stupid linker error last night, and I just checked my project and apparently I never added the necessary .cpp files (they existed on disk but were missing from the project). It can be easy to overlook this, so heads-up.