# c++ istream operator overloading unresolved

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, istream

source.h:

```
#include <iostream>
class date{
public:
std::string str_time;
friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& para_stream, date& para_date);
};
```

source.cpp:

```
#include "source.h"
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& para_stream, date& para_date)
{
  istream >> para_date.str_time;
  return istream;
}
```

ERROR:
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits > & __cdecl src::operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits > &,class src::date &)" (??5src@@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV12@AAVdate@0@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall src::DB::del_vouc(int const &)" (?del_vouc@DB@src@@QAE_NABH@Z)    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\foodstore\foodstore\DB.obj  foodstore

Comment: You forgot to link with the definition. It has nothing to do with overloading, operators, or `istream`.

Comment: The error is talking about a DB object file - how are you building your stuff?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LNK2019 error c++ unresolved external symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730135/lnk2019-error-c-unresolved-external-symbol)

Comment: @doctorlove yes, I know that as well, but when I remove this operator overloaded functions, it doesn't give error.

Comment: You really should read the post from anatolyg's comment. The `include` keyword only loads the include file at compile time. But to build an executable you have to link `source.o` with you main source.

Comment: Link is about libraries; include is about compiling

Comment: @doctorlove DB file is where I exacute the overloaded operator function.

Comment: Maybe because you have defined it in the source.cpp file, but not told the world about it in the header, it's not visible outside the translation unit?

Comment: @doctorlove "told the world about it in the header", sorry, I don't quite understand what that means, How can I do that?

Comment: You gave a function in a cpp file. If you declare it in the header, anything including the header can use it. If you don't declare it in the header it stays "hidden" in the source file

Comment: @doctorlove so, I should put the overloaded function in header file?

Comment: You'd need to mark it inline then; alternatively just put the declaration, `std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& para_stream, date& para_date);` and leave the definition in the cpp file

Comment: @doctorlove wow, it worked. Thanks! But why do I need to put inline? can you explain?

Comment: Going to add an answer cos these comments got out of hand

Comment: Hope the answer makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker is complaining about `src::DB` having an "unresolved external symbol"

You have defined a function inside source.cpp, so it remains internal to this file (translation unit).

If you add a declaration to the header file, like this

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& para_stream, date& para_date);
```

it becomes available externally, rather than "hidden" inside the cpp file.

Alternatively, you can define (rather than just declare) it in the header file, but it MUST be marked inline otherwise you end up with a definition every time the header is included.

Comment: But, how about if I wanna do this externally? is that possible?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean - you need to export a symbol (via the header) to let other files find it during linking

Answer (score 0):

```
istream >> para_date.str_time;
return istream;
```

These two lines should be as :

```
para_stream >> para_date.str_time;  // para_stream is the object of class istream 
return para_stream ;
```

You should use the object of the class `para_stream`, not the class. After this change,it compiled successfully in my system.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've done that, but it still say unresolved

Comment: @TrisYang It worked in my system. I am using windows 10.

Comment: @TrisYang  Same code, with two modifications, mentioned in the answer

Comment: did you separate the file? (Cpp and header)

Comment: @TrisYang  Yes, I did separate both the files

Comment: @TrisYang Check the image, I posted in the answer.

Comment: @TrisYang I added the header file too.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: c++17 or c++1995?

Comment: I am using g++ 9.20.  C++11 standard.

Comment: have you tried it in visual studio (IDE)?

Comment: I don't have Visual studio.  I am using Visual Studion Code (VS code).

Comment: I'm using c++ 11, did you try c++11?

Comment: In my `c_cpp_properties.json` file  `cppStandard : C++11`.  So, I did it with C++11 standard only.