# Getting Boost asio to work

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to use the Boost asio library to for sockets.

I installed boost using homebrew `brew install boost`

After it was built I tried [the tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2/src.html) for creating a server on boost's website.

All I did was paste that code into a file called `main.cc`

When I try to compile `g++ main.cc` I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccTbzxpk.o
  boost::asio::error::get_system_category()    in ccTbzxpk.o
  boost::system::error_code::error_code()in ccTbzxpk.o
"boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccTbzxpk.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are `linker errors`. If you read the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html):

> The following libraries must be available in order to **link programs
>   that use Boost.Asio**:
>
> **Boost.System for the boost::system::error_code and
>   boost::system::system_error classes.** 
>   Boost.Regex (optional) if you use
>   any of the read_until() or async_read_until() overloads that take a
>   boost::regex parameter. 
>   OpenSSL (optional) if you use Boost.Asio's SSL
>   support.
>
> **Furthermore, some of the examples also require the Boost.Thread,
>   Boost.Date_Time or Boost.Serialization libraries.**

Now, the errors you posted all say: `boost::system`, this means you need to link  like this (assuming everything is the default):
`g++ main.cc -lboost_system`

Please read [What do 'statically linked' and 'dynamically linked' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311882/what-do-statically-linked-and-dynamically-linked-mean/311889#311889) for in-depth information about linking.

Comment: hmm when linking like you suggested I get `ld: library not found for -lboost_system`

Comment: You'll have to add the library path as well with -L.

Comment: @Deekor: As ppl already mentioned add the library path, something like `-L/home/boost/lib/` before `-lboost_system`.

Comment: @Deekor: I'm not a mac user, but try `-lboost_system-mt` instead.

Comment: Although when I run `./a.out` I get `bind: Permission denied` if its not one thing its another

Comment: @Deekor: You need to execute the code with root permissions, try `sudo ./a.out`