# Super class valiable value over sublclass variable with the same declaration

Tags: global-variables

Hello I found a question like this. The final answer printed by the main method is 3. But what I feel is the answer should be 13. When the new Bar() object is created, its constructor is called. the super() first line, would call back the Super method's constructor and assign a as 3.  When call returns back to Bar() constructor "a" will be assigned to 8. Then after invoking addFive() this.a will be 13. So finally at the print statement by using the object Bar() referenced by n, calls a. Isn't it should be 13. How did the super calss "a" value print? please someone help me to sort it out.

```
 public class _416 {
        public int a;
        public _416(){
        a=3;
        }
        public void addFive(){

        a+=5;
        }
    }
    class Bar extends _416{

        public int a;
        public Bar(){
        a=8;
        }

        public void addFive(){
        this.a+=5;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            _416 n=new Bar();
            n.addFive();
            System.out.println("Value="+n.a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry it should be three I missed one concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not polymorphic in java, your methods are polymorphic, so when you access a variable it is statically linked.

Thus your code `n.a` is statically linked with the `a` instance variable of `_416` class as the reference `n` is of type `_416`

So when you call `n.addFive();` it actually call the method of `Bar` (polymorphism). And in this method you add the `5` to the instance variable of `Bar` class and becomes `13` on the other hand instance variable of `_416` remains intact which is `3`.

Thus when you execute `System.out.println("Value="+n.a);` it prints the value of instance variable of `_416` which is `3`

#### Edit

Statically linked mean that your compiler resolves your ivar/methods at compile time and dynamically linked means that your compiler defers the linking for run time. That's the brief idea for more you can read this [thread on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311889/468724)

Comment: Ahh ok.. Then does it mean that, though method calling decides based on real object created, variables are called based on its reference type? :) what did you mean by statically linked?

Comment: And if I need to print 13. Wht should I do?

Comment: For printing 13 there are several ways. One is to create a new reference `Bar b = (Bar)n;` and then `sop(b.a);`.

Comment: @user3789200 You can also cast n to `Bar` type: `System.out.println("Value=" + ((Bar)n).a);`

Comment: Oki... Thanks alot for both of u... :) really appreciate your valuable help.. Now I am in a dilemma, thinking that whose answer I must select as the correct 1... :D Can't even vote... :( Btw thanks again for help...

Comment: @user3789200 Hiroshi stack is great site to help each other keep on asking and answering.

Answer (score 1):

Because both superclass and subclass have a field called `a`, you've got two fields called `a` but field from superclass is [hidden](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html).

Let's see what happens in your code:

```
_416 n=new Bar();
```

Above code creates an instance of `Bar` class. But, since `Bar` is a subclass of `_416`, The constructor of `_416` is called, which initializes field `a` from `_416` class. After this, constructor of `Bar` is called, which initializes field `a` from `Bar`. then you 've got actually two fields:

- `n` from `_416` = 3
- `n` from `Bar`  = 8

Then, when this code is executed:

```
 n.addFive();
```

It calls overriden method `addFive()` from `Bar` class. This method increases value of `a` from `_416` class. So, you've got:

- `n` from `_416` = 3
- `n` from `Bar`  = 13

And, when, you are using field `n.a` here:

```
System.out.println("Value="+n.a);
```

, you are using field from `Bar` class. That's why printed value is 3.