# Include opencv and boost libraries in .exe c++

Tags: eclipse, opencv, boost, c++14, static-libraries

After searching a lot I have been completely unable to find an answer to my issue.

I have worked in a c++ source code using boost and opencv libraries, but now I want to create an executable which I can run in another computer with the same OS (Linux in this case) but without that libraries (i.e. the exe should contains them) Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you for your help

PD: I am using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to now you have dynamically linked the libraries, which means that the compiler uses the header files and the linker uses the .lib files to know that there will be .dll files containing th compiled code corresponding to what's declared in the header files.to achieve what you want you need to statically link against the .lib files. This means that you don't need the dlls but your .exw will be enough. 
You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311889/5048049)

Of course you can download the static libraries for boost and open cv or compile them from the source code.