# gcc wont compile to an executable

Tags: gcc, compilation

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    // printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

gcc --version

gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gcc -O0 -g -o helloworld -c helloworld.c

This is a fresh system built from scratch today. Ubuntu 18.04.

Produces a helloworld file but not executable if I make it so and try and run it i get

$ chmod +x helloworld

$ ./helloworld

bash: ./helloworld: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

However seems to compile my large project without any problem.

Even though its a fresh system I reinstalled gcc but no difference.

Comment: Why did you pass the `-c` flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-c` flag instructs `gcc` to turn a source file into an *object* file for later linking into an executable.

Making the object file executable will in no way help with trying to run it, you need to link it and produce a *real* executable. Probably the easiest way to do that is to get rid of the `-c` from your command line.

If you had something more complicated (such as multiple source files that you wanted to compile separately and then link all the objects together), the `-c` flag would be useful.

However, since you have *one* source file that you want to make an executable from, just use:

```
gcc -O0 -g -o helloworld helloworld.c
```

For what it's worth, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311882/what-do-statically-linked-and-dynamically-linked-mean/311889#311889) may provide more infomation on the various stages of producing an executable. It's specifically covering the difference between static and dynamic linking but the answer provides a good overview of the compile/link distinction as well.